# Using multiple ServiceStack's auth providers throws error

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I intend to use 2 ServiceStack's auth providers: one custom provider based on `CredentialsAuthProvider` called `remotecreds` and the built-in `JwtAuthProvider`.  My AppHost registration code looks like this

```cs
appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new UserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[]
                {
                    new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                    {
                        RequireSecureConnection = false,
                        HashAlgorithm = "RS256",
                        PublicKeyXml = publicKeyXml,
                        Audiences = new List<string> { $"{AppSettings.GetDictionary("Auth")["Url"]}/resources" },
                        PopulateSessionFilter = PopulateSessionFilter
                    },
                    new RemoteCredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                    {
                        PopulateSessionFilter = PopulateSessionFilter                  
                    },

                }));
```

When I authenticate with the custom auth provider (`POST /auth/remotecreds`), ServiceStack returns the following error although the auth provider's code has been executed correctly

```
{
    "responseStatus": {
        "errorCode": "NotSupportedException",
        "message": "PrivateKey required to use: RS256",
        "stackTrace": "[Authenticate: 25/04/2019 9:59:25 AM]:\n[REQUEST: {provider:remotecreds,userName:admin,password:Pa$$word123}]\nSystem.NotSupportedException: PrivateKey required to use: RS256\r\n   at ServiceStack.Auth.JwtAuthProvider.GetHashAlgorithm(IRequest req) in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack\\Auth\\JwtAuthProvider.cs:line 87\r\n   at ServiceStack.Auth.JwtAuthProvider.CreateJwtBearerToken(IRequest req, IAuthSession session, IEnumerable`1 roles, IEnumerable`1 perms) in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack\\Auth\\JwtAuthProvider.cs:line 118\r\n   at ServiceStack.Auth.JwtAuthProvider.Execute(AuthFilterContext authContext) in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack\\Auth\\JwtAuthProvider.cs:line 57\r\n   at ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Post(Authenticate request) in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack\\Auth\\AuthenticateService.cs:line 253\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, Object instance, TRequest requestDto) in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack\\Host\\ServiceRunner.cs:line 133",
        "errors": []
    }
}
```

If I comment out the `JwtAuthProvider` registration in AppHost, the same call above succeeds.

So here I'm confused why ServiceStack invokes `JwtAuthProvider` while I clearly authenticated against my custom auth provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `JwtAuthProvider` is misconfigured, if you want to use an `RSA*` hash algorithm it needs to be [configured with the private key](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#jwt-signature):

```
new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings) { 
    HashAlgorithm = "RS256",
    PrivateKeyXml = AppSettings.GetString("PrivateKeyXml") 
}
```

It would still be trying to authenticate with your Custom AuthProvider but if you have the `JwtAuthProvider` registered it will be trying to populate the `AuthenticateResponse` with the [JWT token in BearerToken](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#retrieve-token-from-central-auth-server-using-credentials-auth), so when users authenticate against your Auth Provider, e.g:

```
var clientnew JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);

var authResponse = client.Post(new Authenticate {
    provider = "remotecreds",
    UserName = username,
    Password = password,
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

They will have access to the JWT Token populated in:

```
var jwt = authResponse.BearerToken;
```

So if it's properly configured it will return a populated JWT Token in `BearerToken` or 
if you remove your `JwtAuthProvider` it wont attempt to populate it.

Comment: Thank you, that works! However, I've also found out that I should use `JwtAuthProviderReader` instead in my use case. Essentially, I have a separate Identity Server, and I just want to verify JWT token issued by that server in Service Stack. If I verify it manually using request filter, I won't be able to take advantage of `[Authenticate]` and the likes. If I use `JwtAuthProvider`, then Service Stack will require the private key of the Identity Server, which is unreasonable. `JwtAuthProviderReader` verifies token, maps it to session, and doesn't generate token in my custom authentication flow